# Can't Add View from Controller in VS 2015 : "There was an error running the selected code generator"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm following a video tutorial where I'm required to create an empty `ASP.NET Web` Application with `MVC`, using `Visual Studio 2015`, being new to ASP.NET world, I'm following step by step.

I got my project created well, next step adding a View from an existing `Controller`, I got hit by a messagebox error saying :

> Error :
> There was an error running the selected code generator:
> 'Invalid pointer (Exception from HRESULT:0x80004003(E_POINTER))'

I Googled the problem, found similar issues, but none led to a clear solution, some similar problems were issued by anterior version of VisualStudio, but as I said none with a clear solution.

To clarify what I experienced, here's what I've done step by step :

**Chosen a ASP.NET Web Application :**

[image]

**Chosen Empty Template with MVC checked :**

[image]

**Tried to `Add View` from a Controller :**

[image]

**Some settings ...**

[image]

**The Error :**

[image]

What's causing this problem and What is the solution for it ?

**Update :**

It turns out that even by trying to add the View manually I get the same error, adding a view is all ways impossible !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error : Package restore failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44509694/error-package-restore-failed)

Comment: This solution worked for me:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Try clearing the ComponentModelCache, the cache will rebuild next time VS is launched.

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Delete everything in this folder C:\Users\ `[your users name]` \AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
3. Restart Visual Studio

14.0 is for visual studio 2015. This will work for other versions also.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Neither did any of the other solutions listed in any of the other answers to this question.

Comment: This worked for me, though my error was different. I want to Kiss somebody. I was stuck with the trying to work around it for quite some time.

Comment: A simple restart of VS 2017 did it for me

Comment: path for me C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_eed87ff6\ComponentModelCache

Comment: I did this in 2019 and the "Add View" item is gone from the menu completely, I only have "Add MVC 5 view" now (which I don't use, I'm on 4)

Comment: Thank you so much. It Worked like a charm for me.
Ps using Visual Studio 2017

Comment: In VS 2019 you have to go to both 16.0 fb sections and do the same thing ;)

Comment: I also found out that my Tools and Framework.sqlserver just got deleted by itself in my packages

Comment: Worked for VS 2022 too, thank you.

Answer (score 17):

I had this issue with a different error message "-1 is outs the bounds of.."

The only thing that worked for me, was to remove the project from the solution by right clicking the project and selecting 'Remove'. Then right click the solution, Add Existing Project, and selecting the project to reload it into the solution.

After reloading the project, I can now add views again.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you

Answer (score 7):

I have the same error but in VS 2017 when I create a controller. I did it in the same way as @sh.alawneh wrote. Also, I tried to do what @longday wrote. But It didn't work. Then I tried in another way:

- Right click on the target folder.
- From the list, choose Add => New Item.

There I choose a new controller and it works fine.

Maybe I'll help someone.

Comment: I cleared the folder, unloaded the project, did `dotnet restore`. None of it worked. But this did.

Comment: Verify the project properties and select the right framework for me in 2017 it was pointing to 4.5.1 i changed to 4.8 it worked

Answer (score 5):

Follow these steps to add a view in a different way than the typical way:

- 1) Open Visual studio.
- 2) Create/open your project.
- 3) Go to Solution Explorer.
- 4) Right click on the target folder.
- 5) From the list, choose **Add**.
- 6) From the child list, choose **MVC View Page (Razor)** or  **MVC View Page with layout (Razor)**.
- 7) If you select the second choice from the previous step, you should choose a layout page for your view from the pop up window.
- 8) That's it!

If you cannot open the view that you are created, simply right click on the view file, choose **Open with**, and select **HTML (web forms) editor** then okay.

Comment: The error was caused by a code generator, i.e VS trying to scaffold the view based on a selected model class. Adding a view using your method allows for no scaffolding, and you have to hand code all the layout for the view.

Answer (score 3):

In my case helped the following:

1. Restart VS
2. Solution Explorer => Right click on solution => **Rebuild solution**

Comment: Worked for me in VS 2017

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem in this way

first I had Entity frameworks with the latest version 5.0.5

[image]

and the code generation package with version 5.0.2

[image]

so I just uninstalled Entity frameworks and install version 5.0.2 as the same for code generation  package

and its worked

Comment: I was getting "There was an error running the selected code generator", VS was trying to Install "microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegeneration.design".
I had to downgrade "microsoft.aspnetcore.app" from 2.1.27 to 2.1.1 version same as "microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegeneration.design".

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on the project under the solution and click unload Project,

you will see that the project is unloaded, so now re right-click on it and press load project

then try to add your controller

Comment: Worked for me in VS 2019

Comment: Remember to Clean Solution first and then rebuild the solution... It will fetch the nuget packages as well wherever required...

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume you are using a datacontext in a DLL, well, it was my case, and I dont know why I have the same error that you describe, I solve it creating a datacontextLocal on the backend project. then I pass the Dbset to the correct datacontext and delete the local (you can let it there if you want, can be helpfull in the future

if you ready are using it in local datacontext, create a new one and then pass the Dbset to the correct one

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET Core check if you have the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools` nuget package and it corresponds to your project version.

Comment: `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools` is not compatible with asp.net 3.1
One should consider installing `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design`

Answer (score 1):

`C:\Users\{WindowsUser}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_8183e7d1\ComponentModelCache`

Remove from this folder for VS 2019 ....

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a Core 3 app and had this issue pop up when adding a controller. I figured out that the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design package was updated with a .net 4.x framework dll. Updating to the project to Core 3.1 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar proble to this one. I went through 2 appraches for solving this.

## First Approach: Not The Best One...

I had created a project on VS2019, and tried to add a controller using VS2022. Not possible. I'd get an error every time.

[image: searchFolders]

`Error ... Parameter name: searchFolder`

Only from VS2019 I'd be able to scaffold the controller I needed. Not the best solution really... But it worked nevertheless.

You could try adding what you need from a different VS version.

## Second Approach: The Best One

After further research I found this solution.

From Visual Studio Installer, I added the following components to my VS22 installation:

[image: .NET Framework project and item templates]

`.NET Framework project and item templates`

This made possible to add the controller I needed on VS22.

---

I know this solution does not point exactly to your problem, but it's maybe a good lead to it. Like you, when I was trying to add/scaffold the controller, I was able to see all the components in the wizard, but in creation after naming it, the error was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

just in case someone is interested - the solution with clean cache didnt work for me. but i've managed to solve an issue but uninstalling all .Net frameworks in the system and then install them back one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted my visual studio and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the ComponentModelCache,

1.Close Visual Studio

2.Delete everything in this folder C:\Users\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache

3.Restart Visual Studio

4.Check again

this also used VS2017 to get solution

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue that prevented the code generation from working. Apparently, my metadata had unknown properties or values. I must admit I did not try all the answers here but who really wants to reinstall vs or download any of the numerous Nuget packages being used.

Cleaning the project worked for me (Build->Clean Solution) The generator was using some outdated binaries to build the controller and views. Cleaning the solution removed the outdated binaries and voilà.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently trying to familiarise myself with MVC 4. I've been developing with MVC 5 for a while, but I need to know MVC 4 to study for my MCSD certification. I'm following a tutorial via Pluralsight, targeting much older versions of Entity Framework, and MVC, (the video was released in 2013!)

I hit this exact same error 2 hours ago and have been tearing my hair out trying to figure out what is wrong. Thankfully, because the project in this tutorial is meaningless, I was able to step backward throughout the process to figure out what it was that was causing the object ref not set error, and fix it.

What I found was an error within the structure of my actual solution.

I had a MVC web project set up ('*ASP.NET Web Application (**.NET Framework**)*'), but I also had 2 class libraries, one holding my Data Access Layer, and one holding the domain setup for models connecting to my database.

These were both of type '*Class Library (**.NET Standard**)*'.

**The MVC project did not like this.**

Once I created new projects of type '*Class Library (**.NET Framework**)'*, and copied all the files from the old libraries to the new ones and fixed the reference for the MVC web project, a rebuild and retry allowed me to scaffold the View correctly.

This may seem like an obvious fix, don't put a .NET Standard project alongside a .NET Framework one and expect it to work normally, but it may help others fix this issue!

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the Types used in the Model Class.

Using the Types like this:

```
    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "Image")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase ImageUpload { get; set; }


    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "Valid from")]
    public Nullable<DateTime> Valid { get; set; }


    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "Expires")]
    public Nullable<DateTime> Expires { get; set; }
```

No longer works in the Code Generator. I had to remove these types and scaffold without them, then add them later.

It is silly, `[NotMapped]` used to work when scaffolding.

Use the base Types: int, string, byte, and so on without Types like: DateTime, List, HttpPostedFileBase and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I have been scratching my head with this one too, what i found in my instance was that an additional  section had been added to my Web.config file.  Commenting this out and rebuilding solved the issue and i was now able to add a new controller.

Answer (score 0):

A simple VS restart worked for me. I just closed VS and restarted.

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me. I just updated Visual Studio (updates were available) and suddenly it just works.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved after installed EntityFramework from nuget package manager into my project. Please take a look on your project references which already been added EntityFramework. Finally I can add the view with template after I added EntityFramework to project reference.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the .vs folder inside the solution directory worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old thread, but I came across it whilst working on my issue.  Mine was caused because I had renamed one of my Model classes.  Even though the app built and ran fine, when I tried to add a new controller I got the same error.  For me, I just deleted the class I had renamed, added it back in and all was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Database Connection string and if there any syntax errors in the appsettings.json it will return this error.

Answer (score 0):

Another common cause for this, which is hinted in the build log, is your IIS Express Web Server is running while you are trying to build a scaffold. Stop/Exit your web server and try building the scaffold again.

Answer (score 0):

Try unload and reload project (solution).

Answer (score 0):

So, i had this problem in vs2019.

- none of the other suggestions helped me

This is what fixed me:

- upgrade .net 5.0 dependencies to 5.0.17

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had same error. what I did was to downgrade my `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` to version `3.1.30` since my .net version was `netcoreapp3.1`. This means the problem was a mismatch of the versions.

So check your version of dotnet and get a matching version of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` that supports it.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33024487)

Answer (score 0):

I just turned off my v2ray proxy and it worked

Answer (score -1):

I was also trying. I was facing face problem. I searched on google. I found an error solution. So I am sharing it with you.

- You should clear ComponentModelCache in your directory.
  1 First Close Visual Studio
  2 delete everything from this path
  C:\Users\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0\ComponentModelCache
  3 Visual Studio Start Again
  Hopefully, error will finish

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your answer is the same as the accepted answer. Please edit it and explain why did you add another answer