# Error: "There was an error running the selected code generator: Package restore failed"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to add controller to my solution in ASP.NET Core project:

[image]

When I try to do so I get this error:

[image]

I get the same message for adding minimal dependencies and full dependencies for controller.

Comment: Many of the answers below were correct at the time. While the concepts remain, the details seem significantly different for .Net Cor 3.1 with .Net 5.0 Entity Framework...

Comment: Updating all the packages to the latest version solves this issue. Example of how to do the bulk update: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74031354/8644294

Answer (score 57):

I also had this issue. "Add Controller>API Controller with actions, using Entity Framework" would give the "Package Restore Failed" error.

As Anish stated, it seems to be due to package versions being mis-aligned. I was able to resolve this issue using "Manage NUGET Packages for Solution", then performing an "Update All". This set my AspNetCore version to 2.1.5 and resolved my "Package Restore Failed" error, but then led to another error, "NETCore version 2.1.5 not found". Apparently the scaffolding code generator needs the AspNetCore and the NETCore versions to be in sync, so I manually downloaded and installed the NETCore version 2.1.5 from Microsoft Downloads.  This worked, and I was finally able to generate Controllers.

Answer (score 17):

I was getting the same error while making a new controller. 
I've fixed it like this.
Actually, VS only had the Offline Package source and could not resolve the packages needed.

Add the online reference:
Tools > nuget package manager > package manager settings > Package Sources

Add source: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Answer (score 15):

1. VS2019 [5.0].
2. Update NuGet Packages (Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Manage
   NuGet packages for solution -> Click on the **Updates tab**, select all
   and run update.
3. Solution -> Clean
4. solution -> Build
5. create a Controller.

I try everything but the above method work for me

Comment: Thanks, this finally did the trick for me as well!

Answer (score 14):

**If no answer works for you**, try running the code generator from the command line.

For my sln with multiple projects, with **net 5 and some NuGet packages of 5.0.5 and some of 5.0.2**, Only code generator through the command line worked. Make Sure it is installed.

or **install** it by the following command

```
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
```

or **update** it by the following command

```
dotnet tool update -g dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
```

The basic code generator commands can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/tools/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator?view=aspnetcore-5.0#arguments)

Some of them are:

```
Generator           Operation
area                Scaffolds an Area
controller          Scaffolds a controller
identity            Scaffolds Identity
razorpage           Scaffolds Razor Pages
view                Scaffolds a view
```

For example:

```
dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator identity --dbContext MyDbContextClass
```

To get help:

```
dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator [YourGenerator] -h
```

Comment: Thanks ! The only solution that worked for me. The parameters are different than your example. 
What worked for me : 
dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator razorpage -dc MyContext -m MyModel -udl -outDir areas/MyModel

Comment: This command showed what package was missing. After including that, it did generate the files!

Answer (score 9):

I encountered this issue with net5.0, specifically against version 5.0.5 of some dependencies. I downgraded my nuget packages from 5.0.5 to 5.0.4 for these:

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.4"
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.4"
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="5.0.4" 
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.4"
```

Comment: tried but did not work, running scaffolding through command line worked with mismatching libraries

Comment: Running a full package update in a .net 5 project did the trick for me

Comment: I tried every solution above. This is the one that worked for me using .NET 5. I am wondering if using a lesser version of .NET 5 is worth just having the ability to scaffold controllers using EF.

Comment: I just downgraded one version, and it worked.. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I just recently ran into the same issue.

I resolved it by eventually taking a look at each individual .csproj files included in my solution and fixing all the versions of the microsoft libraries that were included.

I changed the metapackage that i was referencing from "Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" to "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App", i then loaded up the reference list on nuget for the "App" package and removed any references to libraries that are already included in the metapackage.

I then made sure that i fixed the versions of any outstanding packages to match the version of the metapackage that the project automatically chooses ie in my case 2.2.0.

Something that tripped me up was that if you have multiple projects included in your solution you need to make sure that they reference the same metapackage as if there is a version mismatch between projects included in your solution you will get this issue too.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.2.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Changed to this.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: That did the trick. dotnet restore didn't work, clearing the componentcache didn't work. Although I have to change back the PackageReferences after scaffolding because I'm getting some UI-exception (but it doesn't seem to affect the build)

Comment: have you included the CodeGeneration package?

Answer (score 3):

I just had this problem whilst adding a controller to a Core API with Entity Framework project. I'm using VS 16.8.5 with the most recent EF core, version 5.03. The class containing my DBContext class referenced EF 5.03 .

I (eventually!) noticed whilst browsing Nuget that the various code generation packages (none of which were referenced in my .csproj file, I think because ASP.Net core ships as a framework since 3.0 but correct me if I am wrong someone!), and in particular Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.EntityFrameworkCode were 5.02. I didn't touch my ASP.Net project, instead I dowgraded the other EF projects to 5.02 and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

What fixed it for me after I couldn't scaffold IdentityFramework was by

1. Checking VS2019 for updates.
2. Update NuGet Packages (Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Manage NuGet packages for solution -> Click on the updates tab, select all and run update.
3. Retry scaffolding identity

Answer (score 2):

I had resolved it by update two files

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration
> and
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design

. Its version should be match with other packages version in application.

Answer (score 2):

Just update the NUGET packages from the Nuget Package Manager.

Answer (score 2):

i have same error. and Update NuGet Packages (Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Manage NuGet packages for solution -> Click on installed.
You need select Version with notice Dependencies.

Example my option is fine with:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFramework Core with version 3.1.12

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools with version 3.1.12

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer with version 3.1.12

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design with version 3.1.5

Comment: I have the same Dependencies version but it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem with a blazor server application version 5.0.5 and Microsoft Identity scaffolding. The highest available version of the CodeGeneration.Design package was 5.0.2, so i downgraded the other Microsoft packages (specially EntityFramework) to 5.0.2 and it solved the problem.

Comment: I solved the same problem in my .Net Core 5.0 Razon pages app.

Comment: No need to downgrade anything. Just update all packages and that will fix it.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/74031354/8644294

Answer (score 2):

I know that some of you might still facing the same issue,
I just did the next in VS 2022,

1- Checked the depencendies on the current project.
[image]

2- Remove all of them

3- Go to dependencies
add a lower version

[image]

and the clean the solution and add the views.

Comment: Yes. Worked for me, too.  It boils down to what I assume is that the nuget packes being used for scaffolding are dependent upon each other and therefore must be compatible by version.  Once I made the appropriate version changes and also made sure they are supported by the .net version for my project it all worked and I could scaffold new controllers and views as normal.  Thanks.

Comment: Need to add nuget.org as one of the package resources then VS is able to locate the correct/compatible package for you. Refer to this, https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/error-running-selected-code-generator-package-rest/515847

Answer (score 1):

Had exactly same problem, in my situation CodeGenerator was missing

I have added this item into ItemGroup in .csproj

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.0" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, but updating all the NuGet Packages has solved the problem.
Right click on <*your project name*> file -> Manage NuGet Packages -> Updates -> Select all packages -> Update

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have some of the older versions of nuget pacakges installed in your project and when you try to scaffold the Asp.net core tries to install the latest packages which are required for scaffolding at this point Asp.net core throws such exception.

I suggest you to update your nuget packages and than try scafolding.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning the solution showed me an error of NuGet packages needed to be updated! I updated them and build the solution. Build Successful and I was able to create the controller class.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to add MVC controller with views using EF for MVC project using `Net5.0`.

Using the following [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/) packages specific versions worked for me, while the problem was solved by using less version than the version of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`, for both `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`, these packages are referenced in the MVC project.

The correct packages are:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="5.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.6">
           <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
           <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
            </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="5.0.2" />   
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this same error when i was trying to scaffold identity template. I resolve this issue by updating nuget packages of the two major project of concerns(I mean the the two projects that has something to do with what i was to implement).

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing this issue.

Please follow this step,

- Clean Your Solution
- Open Nuget Manager
- Check this version Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (I am using 5.0.8)
- Check this version Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design (I am using 5.0.8)
- Check this version Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools (I am using 5.0.8)
- Check this version Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer (I am using 5.0.8)
- Check this version Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design (I am using 5.0.2)

[image: Check this image also]

- After that Rebuild your solution and Create Scaffolding Controller

Comment: In my case Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design package was missing. I also had to downgrade EntityFramework related packages from 6.0.3 to 6.0.2 to match latest stable version of Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design package.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, Here is How I solved the Issue

**There was an error running the selected code generation, 'Package restore failed. Rolling back package canges for web'**

**1**- Check if your Solution has multiple projects, please check their Target Dot.net Framework.(in my case it was .Net Standard 1.6 for class libraries & .NetCoreApp 1.0 for Web Project, I changed it to .NetCoreApp 1.1)

**2**- After having the same framework, clean the web project, Rebuilt and Add new Controller.

If its successful fine otherwise You might encounter another error e.g

**'There was an error running the code generator: 'No executable found matching command "dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator"'**

If you have **project.json** file open it other wise open **.csproj.user** project in note pad, please add following
   
    
  
Please note based on your .net version you might have different version no.

You may find instruction in **ScaffoldingReadMe.txt** file if its generated in your project

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was open the properties of my web project and change the TargetFramework from 2.1 to 2.2. Or to match whatever version of the framework your business and object layer are using.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running .NET Core (and Entity Framework Core) 3.1.x.

I got this exact error and tried updating all the nuget packages and other relevant solutions already mentioned in the answers here.

The issue was simply that my database server was not running (it runs on a local VM). In other words, my database context (i.e. `ApplicationDbContext`) mentioned in the 'Add Controller...' window, was not able to access the db. Once I started the db server, my scaffolding created without issue.

Keep also in mind, the model/class (i.e. table) that the controller and views were referencing had not been created yet (I hadn't run add-migration yet). So, it just needed the db connection only.

It's kind of a silly (obvious?) solution, but very misleading when looking at the 'Package Restore Failed' error message.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with entity framework core sqlite nuget packages. I installed sqlite and sqlite core packages fixed this. Probably a needy package is missing. Also make sure SQL Server and Server Agent are running. Check those on **SQL Server Configuration** > **SQL Server Services** > Right click on **SQL Server or Server Agent and** start the service then restart the server. Guess this might help someone

Answer (score 0):

I just updated EntityFrameworkCore from Version 3.1.10 to 3.1.13 and it solved the problem. My Project file looks like:

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="3.1.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.13">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.5" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue when creating a new 'Identity' scaffolded item.
I managed to get this working by removing everything within the `<ItemGroup>` tags within the csproj file and running the code generator. The generator then installs packages that it needs.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error in Visual Studio 2022 trying to add a view:

[image]

[image]

That was just before when the wizard tries to restore the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design.

[image]

So what I did was to try to add this package to the project in NuGet. When NuGet tried to add this package show me an error of NetCore incompatibility.

```
NU1202: Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design 7.0.7 is not compatible with net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0). Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design 7.0.7 supports: net7.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0)
```

Then, I upgraded the project version to NetCore 7 and retried the package installation. This time the error was different:

```
NU1107: Version conflict detected for Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common. 
Install/reference Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common 4.6.0 directly to project DipuAlba.Seface.Web to resolve this issue. 
 My.Project.Name -> My.Project.Library.Name -> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common (>= 4.6.0) 
 My.Project.Name -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design 7.0.7 -> Microsoft.DotNet.Scaffolding.Shared 7.0.7 -> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features 4.4.0 -> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common (= 4.4.0).
```

I tried to update all to the latest version, but Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design needed the 4.4.0 Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common version and Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp needed the 4.6.0 version.

Finally, I solved it installing a Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp that uses the 4.4.0 version.

Conclusion, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design NuGet package needs to be compatible with the current installed packages in the ASP.NET project.

Answer (score 0):

If you are upgrading any nuget package,

1. 1st check if there are new updates in visual studio (Help -> Check
   for updates) and upgrade.
2. Use the latest .Net version you can use if it is compatible with
   your visual studio. You can change it in .csproj
3. Update all packages in nuget packet manager (if you get
   compatibility issues, read the error carefully and use the latest
   versions compatible with each other and manually change in .csproj)
4. Especially check if the
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design version is
   compatible with the TargetFramework.

Clean and rebuild. Now try the code generator/scafold controller.
That resolved the issues I had.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcINK.png)
[image]