# Error: 'Package restore failed rolling back package change for' while running Scaffold-Dbcontext in Entity Framework Core 7.0.14

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-scaffolding

I'm encountering an issue while running `Scaffold-DbContext` using Entity Framework Core 7.0.14; I'm getting an error message

> There was an error running the selected code generator package restore failed rolling back package change for

I'm curious about what steps I should take to resolve this issue.

Versions I'm using:

- .NET Core 7
- Entity Framework Core 7.0.14
- Project GitHub link: [GitHub Link](https://github.com/iamumutcan/E-Commerce-With-Net7)
- Visual Studio 2022

Does anyone have any help or suggestions regarding this issue? Thank you in advance.

[I connect with dbcontext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSdth.png)

[but it doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRWhM.png)

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
     public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
     {
     }

     public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
     public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
     public DbSet<ProductPrice> ProductPrices { get; set; }
     public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
     public DbSet<OrderHeader> OrderHeaders { get; set; }
}
```

I attempted to generate a `DbContext` using `Scaffold-DbContext` in Entity Framework Core 7.0.14 within my .NET Core 7 project. I expected the command to execute successfully and create the necessary `DbContext` based on my database schema. However, during the process, I encountered an error

> There was an error running the selected code generator package restore failed rolling back package change for

Despite multiple attempts, I couldn't resolve this issue. Seeking advice on resolving this error in the context of .NET Core 7 and Entity Framework Core 7.0.14

Comment: According to your error message , it is an package reference issue . I tested with several ways like rebuild project, unify the versions and so on , but same result. You can try to build a new app and add the references one by one to see which causes the error.

Comment: I think you will get your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44509694/error-there-was-an-error-running-the-selected-code-generator-package-restore

Answer (score 0):

Your `"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="7.0.11"` is not compatible with your EF core version, you need to modify the `EF core` relating packages to `7.0.12`

**E_Commerce_Sercer**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="12.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="7.0.14" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.12">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="7.0.12" />  // This is auto-matically installed
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.12">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="7.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Blazor.Grid" Version="19.4.0.56" />
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Blazor.RichTextEditor" Version="19.4.0.56" />
    <PackageReference Include="Syncfusion.Blazor.Themes" Version="19.4.0.56" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\E_Commerce_Business\E_Commerce_Business.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\E_Commerce_DataAccess\E_Commerce_DataAccess.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\E_Commerce_Models\E_Commerce_Models.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\images\product\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**E_Commerce-DataAccess**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="7.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.12">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```