# Detected package version outside of dependency constraint microsoft.aspnetcore.app 2.1.1 requires microsoft.netcore.razor.design.."

Tags: visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

I keep getting this error message:

**there was an error running the selected code generator sequence contains no matching elements** when i try to create a controller in my asp.net core mvc application.

What is the way out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this link to see the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60383062/7960764)

Steps:

on Visual Studio 2017 Click on Tools > Nuget Package Manager > Package Manager Console then run the command below.

Install-Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design -Version 2.1.1