# Problem Creating Controller Entity Framework ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework

I have a problem in my ASP.NET project created with Entity Framework. I am trying to create the controller, but when I click `Add --> Controller`, fill the fields and press Add, it shows me this error:

[image]

I created it as an ASP.NET web application -> .NET Framework 4.7.2 -> Web Forms -> Authentication: Individual User Accounts -> MVC & Web API.

I tried rebuilding the solution, creating back the program and anything worked for me. I hope you can help me.

Comment: did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34992599/cant-add-view-from-controller-in-vs-2015-there-was-an-error-running-the-sele