# there was an error running the selected code generator: 'The value -1 is outside the acceptable range of [0,2147483647]. Parameter name :value'

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

there was an error running the selected code generator: 'The value -1 is outside the acceptable range of [0,2147483647]. Parameter name  :value'

Answer (score 0):

Try hitting the solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57381260/the-value-1-is-outside-the-acceptable-range-of-0-2147483647-parameter-name) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34992599/cant-add-view-from-controller-in-vs-2015-there-was-an-error-running-the-sele/35815094#35815094), those worked for some people.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens when,

you have the **web.config** file for your project **is open in Visual Studio.**
as the solution,

You need to make sure that the **web.config file is closed**.

Now you should be able to create Views without any errors :D Cheers