# Can't create any view anymore, "The value -1 is outside the acceptable range of [0,2147483647]" error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC Web App, and everything was ok until a few hours ago, when something must have gone wrong, and now I cannot create any view anymore, may they be empty or scaffolded. Any idea how to fix it ? (I'm currently using Visual Studio Community 2019 (version is 16.2.1))

I searched and tried some solutions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57381260/the-value-1-is-outside-the-acceptable-range-of-0-2147483647-parameter-name), [this second one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34992599/cant-add-view-from-controller-in-vs-2015-there-was-an-error-running-the-sele/35815094#35815094) or again [this latter one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57269913/error-while-generating-view-in-visual-studio-2019), but nothing worked for me.

The view that I want to create would be for this function (so that would be the classic Details.cshtml view):

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Candidate candidate = db.Candidates.Find(id);
    if (candidate == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
   }
   return View(candidate);
}
```

However, I can't create a view, VS keeps strucking me with the following error, wether I select an `Empty` template or the `Details` one for my view, and wether I choose a `Model class` or not.

> There was an error running the selected code generator: 'The value -1 is outside the acceptable range of [0,2147483647]. Parameter name: value'`
>   (By the way, I checked for any parameter named value in my solution, and there wasn't any)

Please save me from finishing the hole my head is digging inside the wall... Thanks!!

Comment: In visual studio, you can still copy and paste a view, then rename it to the new name.

Comment: Hell I'm feeling so dumb, not even having think about it ... Thank you, saved my life \o/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only answering in order to have a answer to accept and "close" the subject:
As @Bosco said, copying and pasting a view is possible... So I guess this indeed is a solution!