# Visual Studio cannot create view from controller

Tags: visual-studio

When I create the view from controller, this error window keep popping up.

```
There was an error running the selected code generator.
'The value -1 is outside the acceptance range of [0,2147483647].
Parameter name: value'
```

Before this, I also refer from other post like
[Can't Add View from Controller in VS 2015 : "There was an error running the selected code generator"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34992599/cant-add-view-from-controller-in-vs-2015-there-was-an-error-running-the-sele)
.But, this error window still there. How can I solve this error?

Below the code is the controller code. Before edit that, there is no any problem.

```
using Food_Founder.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Food_Founder.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        // GET: User
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult AddOrEdit(int UserID=0)
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]

        public ActionResult AddOrEdit(User Register)
        {
            using (myDatabaseEntities myDatabase = new myDatabaseEntities())
            {
                myDatabase.Users.Add(Register);
                myDatabase.SaveChanges();
            }
            ModelState.Clear();
            ViewBag.SuccessMessage = "Successful register account.";
            return View("AddOrEdit", new User());
        }


        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(User Login)
        {
            using (myDatabaseEntities myDatabase = new myDatabaseEntities())
            {
                var user = myDatabase.Users.Single(u => u.Username == Login.Username && u.Password == Login.Password);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    Session["UserID"] = user.UserID.ToString();
                    Session["Username"] = user.Username.ToString();
                    return RedirectToAction("LoggedIn");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username or Password is wrong");
                }
            }
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult LoggedIn()
        {
            if (Session["UserID"] != null)
            {
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Share your code so that we may see the possibilities (or impossibilities).

Comment: Ok. The code is updated at there. Thanks for remind me that.

Comment: When does the error pop up?  When you run from Visual Studio in Debug mode?

Comment: @TrevorBrooks No, it will pop put when I create view and another controller