# I want to add a controller to my ASP.NET MVC project, but I get an error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I use Visual Studio 2019.

[image]

This error is appearing again and again while adding an ASP.NET MVC 5 controller with views using Entity Framework, I have tried many ways it doesn't remove.

My code:

```
namespace SingletoninMVC.logger
{
    public sealed class Log : ILog
    {
        private Log()
        {
        }

        private static readonly Lazy<Log> instance = new Lazy<Log>(() => new Log());

        public static Log GetInstance
        {
            get { return instance.Value; }
        }

        public void LogException(string message)
        {
            string fileName = string.Format("{0}_{1}.log", "Exception", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
            string logFilePath = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, fileName);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("----------------------------------------");
            sb.AppendLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
            sb.AppendLine(message);

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(logFilePath, true))
            {
                writer.Write(sb.ToString());
                writer.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try the following solution: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/35815094/6630084](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35815094/6630084)

Comment: Is any update? Please check if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, I reproduced the same error with you.

Also, I found the solution. You could try to **rebuild your project** before you add the controller with views using entityframework.

It works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project-> Rebuild
Now try to create controller, it worked for me. Also check the database connection as well.