# Issue with bootstrap when I scaffold Identity on Asp .net mvc 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp .net mvc 6.0 to do an application. After many implementation I decided to user Identity to handle my users. I correctly import it, I can login, logout , sign in etc...

I want to go further in the handle of the users, that is why I decided to scaffold Identity to modify/understand it.

But when I scaffold Idendity I have this issue : [There was an error running the selected code generator: 'the specified bootstrap version '4' is not valid. The valid options are '3,4,5';4'][1]

Thanks

**Edit :**

I fix it : I deleted the bootstrap project in wwwroot -> lib -> bootstrap

I can scaffold now
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/35Yz6.png

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34992599

Comment: I have already tried this way but my issue persists

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, your proposed solution worked for me. Just needed to remember to restore bootstrap afterwards.