# Scaffolding item error with creating the identity, while I was trying to create an ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I am following a tutorial ("Build real world application using ASP.NET Core MVC, Entity Framework Core and ASP.NET Core Identity") and I am at the point where I need to create the identity as a scaffold item.
However, I seem to be running into an error that has to do with the bootstrap version I'm using, I'm just not sure what to do from here.
"There was an error running the selected code generator: 'The specified bootstrap version '4' is not valid. The valid options are '3,4,5'."

I have updated my code generator but it didn't help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is a double for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69668618/issue-with-bootstrap-when-i-scaffold-identity-on-asp-net-mvc-6-0 The person asking there answered his own question

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered a similar problem. It seems that it is related to the recently released .Net 6. I've solved by switching back to .Net 5 and reinstalling all related packages and executing wizard in this environment. After that I migrated back to the .Net 6

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler work around. Remove the wwwroot/lib/bootstrap folder (I simply moved it to another holding location temporarily... It doesn't work to simply right click and exclude it from the project).

Do the scafolding and it should work... then put the folder back.
Worked for me...

Comment: This worked for me but then I got the error: `A file matching the name IdentityHostingStartup.cshtml was not found within any of the folders:`. Solved that using this thread: https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding/issues/1714